# How to position image within tab content

Tags: jquery, html, css

this is probably super simple for someone but I'm using an "accordion" jquery to display a contact list.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="accordion">
         <h3>Section 1</h3> 
        <div>
            <p>test
                <br>Phone: xxxx
                <br>Email: blabla@aejx.com</p>
        </div>
         <h3>Section 2</h3> 
        <div>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
         <h3>Section 3</h3> 
        <div>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
         <h3>Section 4</h3> 
        <div>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What I'd like to do is be able to have the contact's picture appear on the right hand side of each expanded box in the accordion (ideally in the top right so if i end up adding a bio or something the picture appears in the top right of the expanded box).

How would i do that? Tables with no borders? Can someone help me with the code? Thanks :)

Comment: The 'top right' means...in the `h3` element, or in the `div` element *following* the `h3`? And how would you choose the contact's name (is there an attribute somewhere)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you'd want inside the expanded box will need to go inside the `div` elements within the `#accordion`. From there, simply float the image to the right. Give the following a shot:

```
<h3>Section 1</h3>

<div> <!-- content starts here -->
  <img src="contact-image.jpg">
  <p>test
    <br>Phone: xxxx
    <br>Email: blabla@aejx.com
  </p>
</div> <!-- end content -->
```

CSS:

```
#accordion div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#accordion img {
  float: right;
}
```

This is barebones CSS, so you may need to add some `margin` to add appropriate spacing.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I tried that but having no luck. what am i doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/v8kU3/1/

Comment: simply change the CSS. `#accordion` should be `#menu` since you're using `id="menu"`. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8kU3/2/)

Comment: Awesome! Dumb question now, in a typical html window where do I put the css?

Comment: @dave typically, it should go either in the `<head>` section wrapped in a `<style>` tag, or put it all in a `.css` file and link it to your page with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/your-css-file.css">` in the `<head>`. The latter is best